# I want to develop a adf fusion web application project with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am having a problem with update mapping in query based view object. When I use NULLIF function in where clause the application gives the builder error(An unexpected severe error has occurred in JDeveloper, The program may be unstable, which could result in data loss).

Example of my code:

select table1.column1,table1.column2,table2.column3 
from table1 left join table2
on table1.column1 = table2.column1
where 
table1.column1 = nullif(table1.column1,?)

Comment: does this help: https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/jjflash/adf-and-postgresql-122216

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion. I have visited this link before. This does not provide enough information.

Comment: I have modified NULLIF to coalesce. Bu the error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your business components - which flavor of SQL/JDBC are you using? Make sure it is the generic one and not the Oracle specific.